# Using prefix sum to calculate scores of 2 robots in a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

**Background**

I am trying to solve the following [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/grid-game/description/). I have written the below function and it seems to be passing the sample test cases.

**My Code**

```
def gridGame(grid):
    robot_score = 0
    for _ in range(2):
        robot_score = 0
        row_one_sum = sum(grid[0])
        row_two_sum = sum(grid[1])
        row = 0
        col = 0
        while row < len(grid) and col < len(grid[0]):
            # get current points
            robot_score += grid[row][col]
            # subtract points from sum
            if row == 0:
                row_one_sum -= grid[0][col]
            else:
                row_two_sum -= grid[1][col]
            # set current grid to 0
            grid[row][col] = 0
            # figure out next move
            if row == 0:
                if row_two_sum > row_one_sum or col == len(grid[0]) - 1:
                    row += 1
                else:
                    row_two_sum -= grid[row - 1][col - 1]
                    col += 1
            else:
                col += 1
    return robot_score
```

**Test cases i am passing**

```
grid = [[1,3,1,15],[1,3,3,1]]
grid = [[3,3,1],[8,5,2]]
grid = [[2,5,4],[1,5,1]]
```

**Test Case I am Failing**

```
gridGame([[10, 12, 14, 19, 19, 12, 19, 2, 17], [20, 7, 17, 14, 3, 1, 1, 17, 12]])
```

I have tried debugging for 2.5 hours with no luck and i know i can find solutions online but i am trying to understand what i did wrong.

My Over all approach is i need to get sum of each row and then i know if i move right how much more points i can get vs if i move down how much points i can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this grid:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 1 1 1 16
```

When you're at `(0,0)`, the rows 0 and 1 have sum 14 and 20 respectively, so you'll move to row 1. Whereas the ideal strategy would've been to move along row 0, and then move to row 1 at the last column.

It's easy to see how memoization can help you overcome this fallacy, since you can compute the max possible points, starting from the right and moving towards the left. Won't dive much into it since the question is just about where your approach went wrong.